# Обработка атрибутов xml на java

Tags: java, xml

Имеется след. структура XML

```
<accounts>
<account>
<id1></id1>
<id2></id2>
<iban></iban>
<pan></pan> 
</account>
</accounts>
```

где *iban* - некоторый счет
и *pan*  - номер карты
Блоков *account* внутри *accounts* может быть любое кол-во.
Не могу написать на java алгоритм, который бы при пополнении карты пополнял именно этот счет (внутри этого же атрибута *account*).

Comment: Думаю ваш случай **quizful.net/post/sax-parser-java**

Comment: openman2077 error, ранее натыкался на эту статью, и не пробежавшись поверхностно по ней, не придал значения. Хотя структура документа прям почти моя. Спасибо, то что нужно!